# Generating a certain number after $k$ operations. Obtain a formula for this number as a function of $k$

Tags: summation

There are *n* cookies on a table. Adam did this series of steps:
In the 1st step he put 1 cookie in the middle of every two neighbouring cookies, in the 2nd step he put 2 cookies in the middle of every two neighbouring cookies, in the *k*th step he put *k* cookies in the middle of every two neighbouring cookies... Find the formula for computing the number of cookies on the table after the *k*th step.

Now I have found that the formula for it is:
(k+1)!(n-1)+1

However, I got this purely by computing the number of cookies manually for small *k*s and simply observing the patterns.

How can I prove that this formula works, and why does it work?

Comment: By mathematical induction on $k$. Note that the first step is for $k=0$, before Adam did anything.

Comment: Yeah ok, i can prove it by induction, but why does the formula work? It is not intuitive to me why it works. @mathguy

Comment: Fair enough. Can you "see it" (is it intuitive) for the case $n=2$? If the result is true (for WHATEVER reason) for $n=2$, it is easy - and intuitive - to show it is true for $n>2$ also, this time by induction on $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Instead of considering previous pairs of cookies, ignore the one on the far right, so you start with $n-1$ cookies
- and say that at the $k$th step you put $k$ cookies to the immediate right of each previous cookie, in effect multiplying the number of cookies by $k+1$ on the $k$th step
- so from the start you multiply $(n-1)$ by $2,3,4,5,\ldots,k$ and $k+1$, i.e. by $(k+1)!$ to give $(k+1)!\,(n-1)$
- and finally add back the $1$ far right cookie you ignored at the start to give $(k+1)!\,(n-1)+1$